# Unsupported class file major version 61 with TomEE 8

Tags: java, apache-tomee

Tried to follow the answers to other similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi), unfortunately, to no avail. We are upgrading our application from JAVA 7 to JAVA 17. The code compiles just fine, the problem is when we try to run the .war file on apache-tomee-plume-8.0.8.
JAVA_HOME is set properly:
[JAVA_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKUjh.png)

As well as path:
[PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QHje.png)

Here is the log error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read class definition for com.ui.AccountListLight$SubListDataModel

    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1180)

    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:153)

    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:166)

    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory$OpenEJBAnnotationFinder.<init>(FinderFactory.java:546)

    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.newFinder(FinderFactory.java:267)

    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.create(FinderFactory.java:80)

    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.createFinder(FinderFactory.java:69)

    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:878)

    ... 46 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61

    at org.apache.xbean.asm9.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:189)

    at org.apache.xbean.asm9.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)

    at org.apache.xbean.asm9.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:156)

    at org.apache.xbean.asm9.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:277)

    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1176)
```

Yes, I understand that the issue is that I compiled on JAVA 17 and somehow TomEE is trying to run it on an older version (probably JAVA 7 as that was what I had installed before), but considering I removed all JRE/JDK stuff for JAVA 7 on my machine and all there is in it is JAVA 17, how does it keep happening? Thank you for your time.

Comment: What exact version of TomEE are you using?

Comment: apache-tomee-plume-8.0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with Java being unable to read your Java 17-compiled classes. Looking at the stack trace, the problem is that `org.apache.xbean.asm9.ClassReader` is unable to read your class file. This particular ClassReader is one that TomEE uses to load your application. It is not surprising that TomEE can't read Java 17 applications, since the last release was in August, before Java 17 came out. It was itself compiled using an older version of Java. Hopefully a future version of TomEE will fix this issue.

Comment: Doh, that is so obvious now... Yeah, you are right, as soon as we downgrade to JAVA 16 and compile the project with it, everything works. Thanks k314159!

Comment: They said that TomEE 8.0.9 will support Java 17 out of the box so try that when it releases.

Comment: TomEE 8.0.9 supports J17 and is currently under vote :)